# MySQL - ...on duplicate key not updating

Tags: mysql

I have a table user_passwords:

```
user_password_id AI PK
hashPass varchacr(255)
```

When a user resets their password I want to update the row, so this **should**, and **does fail**:

```
insert into user_passwords (user_password_id,hashedPassword)
VALUES('2','$2y$11$pVYR/0hcgOewMn2jgrGx.uGcky5TXxYOPvsbWGyH3VQxZlj3c1QD.')

Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I know that, so I'm trying the following but no rows get updated:

```
insert into user_passwords (user_password_id,hashedPassword)
VALUES('2','$2y$11$pVYR/0hcgOewMn2jgrGx.uGcky5TXxYOPvsbWGyH3VQxZlj3c1QD.')
on duplicate key update hashedPassword=hashedPassword
```

Why is that?

Comment: By `does fail` you mean old password is preserved? Since you are assigning old password, not new, so it must be.

Comment: I mean it says Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY' as shown in post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
on duplicate key update hashedPassword = VALUES(hashedPassword)
```

see also the docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Aargh of course, thanks dude - will accept when I can